# Developing Node.js oracledb apps and deploying to Linux

Tags: node.js, oracle, cross-platform

Having just spent 8 hours trying to complile oracledb on my Windows machine without errors, and now finally getting oracle data returned over nodejs...I am now wondering how I would deploy the nodejs application to a linux host within our enterprise.

I appreciate this is a general question, but I dont want to embark any further if migrating the nodejs app to redhat will cause a load of problems.

Is this a case of running a fresh "npm install oracledb" command on the linux project once it is deployed to linux, or is not as simple as that (I appreciate the linux host would need configuring with the relevant Oracle drivers etc.).

Or perhaps on linux I can do a global install of oracledb "npm install -g oracledb" and then once deployed, the nodejs application would pick up the dependency from the global npm_modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration won't cause problems.  If your Linux machine has the Instant Client basic & devel RPM packages installed, your application's package.json could even simply have a dependency on 'oracledb'.

If you have Instant Client zips, you could put them in the default location used by node-oracledb: `/opt/oracle/instantclient` so you don't have to set `OCI_*_DIR`.  Also check the [install doc](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md) about using `FORCE_RPATH` (or you will have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or use `ldconfig`)

If the pre-setup is hard to manage, you could just preinstall node-oracledb globally before deploying your app, as you indicated.  You may need to set `NODE_PATH` to the node_modules sub-directory that oracledb gets installed into:

`export NODE_PATH=/opt/local/node/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64/lib/node_modules`